# VB.Net - Is form level scope a thing?

Tags: vb.net

In an assignment, I've been told to show use, and explain scope in general, local scope, global scope, and form level scope.

My tutor sometimes gets his terms mixed up, is this one of those times? Because I can't find anything online about form level scope.

Bonus points for giving a VB.Net example of of form (or similar - possibly module) level scope.

Thanks!

Comment: The following link might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t0wsc67.aspx

Comment: Look at @Markus's link. "Form" level scope is going to be either "Module" or "Namespace," depending on your tutor's context. My guess is by "form" he/she meant "program" or "project," since the term "form" really only applies to WinForms. Also, this is really more suited to the oop tag, since scope applies to all object-oriented languages, not just VB.NET.

Comment: "Form" level scope is effectively no different then "Class" or "Object" level scope. (A form is a type of object)

Comment: I did have a look at that first, but I'm still unsure as to what my tutor means by 'form level scope'. Thanks

Comment: If your tutor meant your main form class, then that will be class-level (module-level). If your tutor meant your form project, then you're probably looking at namespace-level. "Form-level" isn't a real thing in OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your tutor meant form in the sense of class-level scope, as a `Form` in Windows .NET development is a class.

Comment: I thought as much. What's the difference then between class and global level scope in terms of where the declaration is within the editor?

Comment: @Simon - true global scope in VB.NET is namespace scope, because there is no way to apply variables to an assembly (i.e. DLL) or across multiple namespaces.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks!